# bindPopup() to markers only when they are clicked on

Tags: javascript, python, html, leaflet, folium

The following html code creates several markers and popups for them. `...` is just a replacement for long things which I've ommitted as they don't have significance in solving my problem. As there are 100s of these markers, creating all the popups in one go results in a very long web load time.

Is there a way to somehow add the popups to the markers only when the marker is clicked on? The code below has already been generated, so I can't rebuild it from scratch using a new logic.

```
var m1 = L.marker(...).addTo(map);
var p1 = L.popup(...);
var v1 = $('<div id="v1"></div>')[0];
p1.setContent(v1);
m1.bindPopup(p1);
vegaEmbed(v1, ...)

var m2 = L.marker(...).addTo(map);
var p2 = L.popup(...);
var v2 = $('<div id="v2"></div>')[0];
p2.setContent(v2);
m2.bindPopup(p2);
vegaEmbed(v2, ...)

var m3 = L.marker(...).addTo(map);
var p3 = L.popup(...);
var v3 = $('<div id="v3"></div>')[0];
p3.setContent(v3);
m3.bindPopup(p3);
vegaEmbed(v3, ...)

.
.
.
and so on
```

**Attempt at Falke Design's Proposed Solution:**

So far I have the following Python code:

```
m = folium.Map(...)

fg = folium.FeatureGroup()

for i in range(0,400):
    p = folium.Popup().add_child(folium.VegaLite(...))
    folium.Marker(...popup = p).add_to(fg)

fg.add_to(m)

m.save('templates/index.html')
```

Which generates the below html:

```
var fg = L.featureGroup({}).addTo(m);

var m1 = L.marker(...).addTo(fg);
var p1 = L.popup(...);
var v1 = $('<div id="v1"></div>')[0]; 
p1.setContent(v1);
m1.bindPopup(p1);
vegaEmbed(v1, ...)
.
.
.
and so on up to 400
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way. You can add to each marker a click event and then add the popup.

```
var fg = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

var m1 = L.marker([51.505, -0.09]).addTo(fg);
var v1 = '<div id="v1">v1</div>';
m1.popcontent = v1; //custom property to safe the html to the marker
var m2 = L.marker([51.505, -0.094]).addTo(fg);
var v2 = '<div id="v2">v2</div>';
m2.popcontent = v2;
var m3 = L.marker([51.505, -0.096]).addTo(fg);
var v3 = '<div id="v3">v3</div>';
m3.popcontent = v3;

fg.on('click',function(e){
    var layer = e.layer;
  layer.bindPopup(layer.popcontent).openPopup();
});
```

If your html is updated in `vegaEmbed` you have to save the html id to the marker and then read it out.

```
var m1 = L.marker([51.505, -0.09]).addTo(fg);
var v1 = 'v1';
m1.popcontent = v1; //custom property to safe the id to the marker

fg.on('click',function(e){
    var layer = e.layer;
    layer.bindPopup($("#"+layer.popcontent).html()).openPopup(); // or document.getElementById(layer.popcontent).innerHTML;
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/56dLkq9h/

Comment: Hi Falke, thanks so much for your solution. As my html code is generated from Python (using folium), is there a way to set it up in Python, and then add the fg.on('click') later in the html file? I've updated my code above to include the Python code.

Comment: I've also included the html output of your suggestion, based on my Python code.

Comment: I never coded with folium, but this [marker](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#folium.map.Marker) looks for me you can add custom properties: `folium.Marker(...popcontent = html).add_to(fg)` and I hope this adds the property `popcontent` direktly to the marker. And create the var html like `html = folium.VegaLite(...)`

Comment: Gave it a shot. The popcontent is nowhere to be seen in the html file unfortunately.

Comment: try: `folium.Marker(location, popup=None, tooltip=None, icon=None, draggable=False, popcontent = html).add_to(fg)`

Comment: TypeError: Object of type VegaLite is not JSON serializable at 'm.save('templates/index.html')'

Comment: All good, I'll go with the alternative of show images in popups instead of vega charts to reduce the page loading times. Thanks so much for your time and effort!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly (and I may not), you would like to generate "light" html code from folium code somehow dynamically. If this is the question, the answer is no. You cannot.

From [Folium's doc](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/) :

> folium builds on the data wrangling strengths of the Python ecosystem and the mapping strengths of the leaflet.js library. Manipulate your data in Python, then visualize it in on a Leaflet map via folium.

In fact, your point is [somewhat](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/975) a well known point.